# AWS SES Programmatic Delay

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does anyone know if there is a way to programatically delay the send time of a SES email? I want to queue up some emails but have them be sent a few days apart. Didn't know if there was a mechanism inside of SES to do this or if I need to roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question, but this capability does not exist in AWS SES at the moment.

I could go into options for rolling your own, but that goes beyond the scope of your original question. And there are of course several options and some might be personal-preference.